# grammar from RFC 2812

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I've got a grammar for the IRC-protocol from RFC 2812:

```
message    =  [ ":" prefix SPACE ] command [ params ] crlf
prefix     =  servername / ( nickname [ [ "!" user ] "@" host ] )
command    =  1*letter / 3digit
params     =  *14( SPACE middle ) [ SPACE ":" trailing ]
           =/ 14( SPACE middle ) [ SPACE [ ":" ] trailing ]

nospcrlfcl =  %x01-09 / %x0B-0C / %x0E-1F / %x21-39 / %x3B-FF
                ; any octet except NUL, CR, LF, " " and ":"
middle     =  nospcrlfcl *( ":" / nospcrlfcl )
trailing   =  *( ":" / " " / nospcrlfcl )

SPACE      =  %x20        ; space character
crlf       =  %x0D %x0A   ; "carriage return" "linefeed"
```

What does the "1*letter" mean? I guess one to infinite occurrences.
And what does "*14( SPACE middle )" mean?
And what dows "14( SPACE middle )" mean?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 2812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812.html)'s *References* section lists **[RFC 2234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2234html)** as the specification of *Augmented BNF for Syntax Specifications*.

There, in section 3.6, we see:

> The operator "`*`" preceding an element indicates repetition. The full
> form is:

> ```
>    <a>*<b>element
> ```

> where `<a>` and `<b>` are optional decimal values, indicating at least
> `<a>` and at most `<b>` occurrences of `element`.

> Default values are 0 and infinity so that `*<element>` allows any
> number, including zero; `1*<element>` requires at  least  one;
> `3*3<element>` allows exactly 3 and `1*2<element>` allows one or two.